# PhpStorm on Ubuntu 18 - Read Only Status (unable to change files)

Tags: phpstorm, ubuntu-18.04

When I open my project with PhpStorm on Ubuntu 18, and when I try to edit file, then pop up window appears "Clear Read-Only Status" with options Clear - Ok.

When I click to clear then again pop up window appears with text "Failed to change read-only status for the following files: ..."

I cant change permissions in my cloned repository (the one I am accessing through PhpStorm) on Ubuntu because then file permissions will be different than ones on online repository.

I can edit and write to files through cli with `sudo nano ..`.

Comment: How? Is there a way to open phpstorm with Sudo and to get then all rights

Comment: what are the permissions of the file you are trying to edit? 
do you want to edit it with with the user that owns the file?

Comment: I registered user as owner of this folder and now it works

Answer (score 5):

Solution to my problem:

Add user as owner of project folder:

> sudo chown -R user project

Answer (score 1):

Changing the owner of the folder solved my issue:

```
sudo chown -R system-name project-folder-location
```